# Как в Python requests.post сделать тоже самое, как это делает curl?

Tags: python, requests, post, curl

Имеется curl образец.

```sh
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://api.platforma.md/pbx/accounts/<accountId>/initSession' \
--header 'x-api-key: test_api_key' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data {...}
```

Как в python `requests.post` сделать тоже самое?

Пробовал так: объявлял строкой url и словарем оба header:

```py
response = requests.post(url, headers={'x-api-key: test_api_key', 'Content-Type: application/json'}
```

На это собственно дается мне ответ:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Что не верно? Дело двух заголовках? в json? В чем-то еще? (api-key верный, перепроверял)

Comment: headers должен быть словарем. В вашем примере это не словарь, а set. Используйте правильный синтаксис. А вообще [вот](https://reqbin.com/curl). там есть конверт в другие языки

Comment: используйте https://curlconverter.com/python/

Comment: @vitidev, интересная утилита :) выдает похожий на рабочий код https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ESVz.png но немного в лоб - код можно упростить :)

Answer (score 1):

Первый способ - json передаем как строку в `data=`, вручную заполняем `Content-Type`:

```
data = '{...}'

headers = {
    'x-api-key': 'test_api_key',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data}
```

Второй способ - `data` описываем как словарь `python`, передаем его в `json=` (`Content-Type` будет автоматически заполнен нужным типом):

```
data = {
    ...
}

headers = {
    'x-api-key': 'test_api_key',
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data}
```